# Number of days between two dates of and index

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I need to subtract the last index value to the first index value in order to get the number of days between two dates.

I've the following format: 2011-04-07 00:00:00

I've tried with this:

```
Years_Count = ( MYDF.index[0] - MYDF.index[-1] ) / 365
```

But I get the following:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'Timedelta'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Timedelta.days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.days.html):

```
Years_Count = ( MYDF.index[0] - MYDF.index[-1] ).days / 365
```